# WARNING in AngularCompilerPlugin: Forked Type Checker exited unexpectedly

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular6

When I'm in development mode and after code changes in my IDE (sometimes) I get this console warning message:

```
WARNING in AngularCompilerPlugin:
Forked Type Checker exited unexpectedly.
Falling back to type checking on main thread.
```

Project based on Angular 6 and Angular-cli 6. More exact versions:

`"@angular/cli": "6.0.8"`
`"@angular/*": "6.0.4"`

I'm running project via VSCode Terminal using `node v8.11.3` and `npm v5.6.0`

[image]

Any `help || explanation` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had that same issue.

Try to check where you instantiate new objects with the TypeScript constructor using the `new yourModel()`.

I fixed that assigning the Object to a variable:

```
const company: Company = new Company();
    if (error.status === 418) {
      company.name = error.statusText;
      return Observable.of(company);
    }
    return Observable.of(company); 
  });
```

Instead of doing:

```
    if (error.status === 418) {
      const company: Company = new Company();
      company.name = error.statusText;
      return Observable.of(company);
    }
    return Observable.of(new Company()); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it has caused me the similar error while I was using Angular Components. This happened when I have tried to include something as the invalid children of that particular component. That particular component works Standalone and I have moved it from the parent. It worked fine.
I was trying to use the checkbox component under mat-form-field that took only labels, hints etc.,